# IModelBinder in WebApi string manipulation

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

In Asp.Net MVC the System.Web.Mvc.IModelBinder allow the follow implementation to change all strings:

```
public class CustomMvcTextBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        ValueProviderResult result = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
        if (result == null)
            return null;

        var value = result.AttemptedValue.Trim().ToUpper();

        return value;
    }
}
```

And then I just add this to ModelBinders:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(string), new CustomMvcTextBinder());
```

However the Asp.Net WebApi implementation System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.IModelBinder has a different implementation returning a bool instead object.

How I could change the string value in the WebApi version of IModelBinder?

```
public class CustomWebApiTextBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public bool BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        ValueProviderResult result = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
        if (result == null)
            return false;

        var value = result.AttemptedValue.Trim().ToUpper();

        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would set `bindingContext.Model` and return `true`:

```
var value = result.AttemptedValue.Trim().ToUpper();
bindingContext.Model = value;

return true;
```

That is assuming your model is just a single string, of course. Otherwise some more object creation/casting might be necessary.

Comment: when to return false?